# View local HTML files using web browser on iPad

Tags: ipad, safari, google-chrome, html

Using a web browser (e.g., Safari, Chrome, etc.) can I view html pages that are stored locally on the iPad? The pages should render properly and execute Javascript/CSS properly.

Comment: Where are these files stored?

Answer (score 4):

Since the files are always local to the app in iOS. You can't open a html with apps like Safari and Chrome to load associated assets (js/images/css).

However, You could use apps like [Documents](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8) to upload the folder and open in app browser (uiwebview).

Should work if the URL to assets in the html are relative.

Comment: As I read your answer, it's basically a no. You can't store documents and have the full browsers open them. Chrome, Safari, etc… due to sandboxing. Yes, most apps embed a less optimized web viewer based on the same framework / WebKit as Safari but without some javascript optimizations.

Comment: Coda launches a local webserver and then opens your documents in the full browser. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coda/id500906297

Answer (score 1):

You can create Web Apps for offline viewing by adding them to the home screen. To do this the web page must be written using HTML5 Offline Application Cache. See the below link for further details.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Answer (score 1):

I always use the GoodReader app to view the local html files. You can try it.

Answer (score -3):

Atomic browser will work it out!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please add some more information so that the OP can clearly understand your answer.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to run HTML, JavaScript and CSS on iOS then I suggest getting an app like Coffe Script at Once

Comment: One line answers with no links or explanations aren't what we're looking for on Ask Different; please enhance this answer with a link to the relevant app and an explanation to what that app does and why you recommend it.